# Do I need to manually destroy the EntityFieldQuery object?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using an EFQ object inside a foreach loop:

```
  //bundle those terms with nodes they each have
  foreach($relevantTerms as $dishType)
  {
    $nodeQuery = new EntityFieldQuery();

    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'food_menu_item')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->execute();

    $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));
    krumo($nodes);
  }
```

After the loop stops executing, am I correct in thinking one instance of $nodeQuery will remain in memory for the rest of the request? Do I need to destroy this using unset() for performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really have to care about this much. Because PHP will clean up all this stuff at the end of the page's request lifetime. If you really want to cleanup this lingering instance of anything you just [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) it as-needed.

Something is fishy with your code as your EFQ is in a loop, but it's not being used in the loop for anything what-so-ever.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry - I did not include the code I was using to send these node IDs into an array for future use. That part actually came later but I did not update it here :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP objects are automatically destroyed when they go out of scope. In your case:

- If `$nodeQuery` is used only inside the `foreach()` loop, that happens when the loop ends
- If `$nodeQuery` is a local variable used in a function, that happens when the function ends
- If `$nodeQuery` is a global variable, that happens when PHP executes the last instruction in the *index.php* file

Considering that in most of the cases you are using a local variable in a function, and a function doesn't create more than a object of that class to keep its reference in different variables, there isn't any performance issue with letting PHP automatically destroy the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! +1 for reminding that the scope does not extend beyond the loop.